# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10015 bytes)

Tags: joomla, accordion

The Full error.

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 805306368 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 10015 bytes) in /home/mvcolleg/public_html/plugins/system/tcshortcodes/core/tc_shtcodes.php on line 152
```

Well I only use these in my articles but this item is link on my JU Flashnews.
Here is my code:

```
 [row][col class="span6"] [tab id="tab2" class="tabbale" button="nav-tabs"] [tab_item title="Book Information"] 
Leviticus: Brazos Theological Commentary on the Bible


Author:
EPHRAIM RADNER
Publisher: 
Anvil Publishing Inc.
Format:      
Book Bound
ISBN:         
97897127336423



[accordion id="sc-accordion" class="accordion"][accordion_item title='About the Author']consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin ornare consectetur sodales. Nulla luctus cursus mauris at dapibus. Cras ac felis et neque consequat elementum a eget turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer feugiat sem eu ligula vulputate consequat. Nulla facilisi. Cras vel elit lectus, at fringilla lorem.[/accordion_item]



[accordion_item title='Student Reviews'][testimonial name="Oscar Vidal" designation=" System Administrator" email="email@email.com" url="#"]
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Aliquam laoreet sodales lacinia. Curabitur ut purus tincidunt. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing laoreet sodales lacinia ut purus. Anime con saed elitr, sed diam nonu eirmo conse tetur sadipscing elitr.
[/testimonial]
[testimonial name="Jeriel Espenorio" designation=" System Administrator" email="email@email.com" url="#"]

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 

Aliquam laoreet sodales lacinia. Curabitur ut purus tincidunt. Ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing laoreet sodales lacinia ut purus. Anime con saed elitr, sed diam nonu eirmo conse tetur sadipscing elitr.


[/testimonial][/accordion_item]



[accordion_item title='External Links and Other Sources'] Proin ornare consectetur sodales. Nulla luctus cursus mauris at dapibus. Cras ac felis et neque consequat elementum a eget turpis. Aliquam erat volutpat. Integer feugiat sem eu ligula vulputate consequat. Nulla facilisi. Cras vel elit lectus, at fringilla lorem.[/accordion_item] [/accordion][/tab_item]

[tab_item title="Description"] This volume, like each in the Brazos Theological Commentary on the Bible, is designed to serve the church--through aid in preaching, teaching, study groups, and so forth--and demonstrate the continuing intellectual and practical viability of theological interpretation of the Bible.[/tab_item]

[tab_item title="Gallery"][carousel]
[carousel_item]





Full Cover Page
[/carousel_item]

[carousel_item]





Full Cover Page
[/carousel_item]



[/carousel][/tab_item][/tab] [/col] [/row]
```

And then I've got this error it seems annoying that I'm happy and contented what I've done then I've got an error since I only use the visual Editor.. 
Kindly help me with this problem. I'm a newbie in Joomla and I'm using it for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it, by writing down a line in "configuration.php" and "configuration.php-dist":

```
ini_mem('memory_limit','12M');
```

Try this ;)